# XFS filesystem different amount of free space, if mounted RW vs RO

Tags: mount, disk-usage, free, xfs

I have big disk (14 TB), and fill it with big files (~100GB each), so I use XFS filesystem. After disk is full (52G free) - I remount partition as read-only, to protect files. And there is 143G of free space, so one more file would fit. Yet, when I remount partition as RW to put one extra file - there are not enough free space again (52G free).

How could I use extra ~100 GB to fit one more file to disk? For this partition I will have only ~130 files, ~100GB each, and disk is ok to be read-only after it's full.

```
root@linux:/etc# df -h /mnt/disk3
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1        13T   13T   52G 100% /mnt/disk3

root@linux:/etc# mount -o remount,ro /dev/sdd1 /mnt/disk3
root@linux:/etc# df -h /mnt/disk3
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1        13T   13T  143G  99% /mnt/disk3

root@linux:/etc# mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdd1 /mnt/disk3
root@linux:/etc# df -h /mnt/disk3
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdd1        13T   13T   52G 100% /mnt/disk3
```

Comment: possibly it's because of a feature of xfs where it dynamically pre-allocates space for files. possibly in RO-mode it doesn't allocate extra space because you can't add to the files anyways? see https://serverfault.com/questions/406069/why-are-my-xfs-filesystems-suddenly-consuming-more-space-and-full-of-sparse-file

Comment: @Esther, thanks for feedback, yet if I understand correctly - pre-allocation is for write-open files, as soon as file is closed - there is no pre-allocation, right?
BTW, files are not appended/updated, they usually are moved from other machine or disk and not modified later.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I could imagine that being the reason. If you see the same "symptoms" as the linked question, then the answer can help you get the space back to be able to use it